# Problema al guardar unos archivos al publicar una aplicación de windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017

resulta que en la carpeta bin\Debug debo meter unos archivos para que al momento de generar el .exe e instalarlo, dichos archivos también queden

Cuando publico la aplicación en la opción Compilar --> Publicar, me generá el .exe, pero lo que meto en la carpeta bin\Debug no me queda. Como hago entonces para generar el .exe y me tome dichos archivos.

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0):

En las propiedades del proyecto selecciona **Eventos de Compilación** e ingresas un comando para copiar algún archivo post compilación.

En el ejemplo de la imagen, se copia el archivo *mi-archivo.dll* en la carpeta *bin/Debug* después de compilar el proyecto

[image]

*$(ProjectDir)/libs* indica que el archivo a copiar se encuentra en la raiz del proyecto dentro de una carpeta llamada libs.